# Zend Framework 2 multifile upload issue

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm trying to upload multiple files at once on Zend Framework 2 but i get the error below:

```
Zend \ Validator \ Exception \ InvalidArgumentException 
Value array must be in $_FILES format
/var/www/eiq/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Validator/File/UploadFile.php
     * @return bool
     * @throws Exception\InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function isValid($value)
    {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            if (!isset($value['tmp_name']) || !isset($value['name']) || !isset($value['error'])) {
                throw new Exception\InvalidArgumentException(
                    'Value array must be in $_FILES format'
                );
```

I mainly followed up-to date documantations on [ZF2 File Uploading - ReadTheDocs](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.file-upload.html) and my related codes are at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ilhnctn/d8bd03077330a2084a5b).  When i dump the $post array it is as below:

```
array (size=2)
  'gallery' => 
    array (size=1)
      'file-upload' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => 
            array (size=5)
              ...
          1 => 
            array (size=5)
              ...
          2 => 
            array (size=5)
              ...
  'submit' => string '' (length=0)
```

But i can' get the `$post['file-input']`, it gives the same error. Can anyone please help

Comment: Show the code of your form/input_filter

Comment: @BreyndotEchse they are actually in the gist file, https://gist.github.com/ilhnctn/d8bd03077330a2084a5b , i didnt want to write the whole code on question

Comment: Sorry, overlooked that

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.validator.file.html#uploadfile), it says the validator is for a single file upload only.

For multiple file uploads, use [Zend\Validator\File\Upload](https://github.com/zf2/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Validator/File/Upload.php).

Comment: unfortunately you are wrong. Even HTML5 Multifile upload fails, it must take the first element of the array, take a look at the i link from my question (readthedocs source)

Comment: Did you try using Zend\Validator\File\Upload instead of Zend\Validator\File\UploadFile?

Comment: No i didn't yet, i have an issue with my local repository, i will either now or tomorrow morning try it and inform you. Thank you very much